# Why is any rightinverse to T injective? The linear transformation $T$: $\mathbb{R}^5 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Could use some help with this.

> The linear transformation $T$: $\mathbb{R}^5 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^4$ is given by
>
> $$ 
> T
> \left[\begin{matrix}
> x_1 \\
> x_2 \\
> x_3 \\
> x_4 \\
> x_5 
> \end{matrix}\right]
> =
> \left[\begin{matrix}
> 2x_1 - 4x_2 - x_3 - 3x_4 + 2x_5 \\
> -x_1 + 2x_2 + x_3 + x_5 \\
> x_1 - 2x_2 -x_3 - 3x_4 - x_5 \\
> -x_1 + 4x_2 -x_3 + x_5 \\
> \end{matrix}\right]
> ,
> x = 
> \left[\begin{matrix}
> x_1 \\
> x_2 \\
> x_3 \\
> x_4 \\
> x_5 
> \end{matrix}\right]
> \in \mathbb{R}^5
> $$

A linear transformation $S$: $\mathbb{R}^4 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ which fullfill $(T \circ S)(y) = y$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}^4$ is called a rightinverse to $T$.

*Why is any rightinverse to T injective?*

I've found two right inverses:

$$
S = 
\left(\begin{matrix}
3 & 1 & -3 & 1 \\
1 & \frac{1}{2} & -1 & \frac{1}{2} \\
1 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} & 0
\end{matrix}\right)^{(-1)}
, x_5 = 0
$$

$$
S' =
\left(\begin{matrix}
2 & -4 & -1 & -3 & 2 \\
-1 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -2 & -1 & -3 & -1 \\
-1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{y_1+y_2}
\end{matrix}\right)
, x_5 = y_1 + y_2 \neq 0
$$

But I'm not sure how I argue and realize as to why any rightinverse to T is injective.

Comment: A rightinverse being injective is true for any functions, not just linear transformations. Let's say $T\circ S=id$. Suppose $S(x)=S(y)$. Can you conclude that $x=y$ from this?

Comment: First, how can you just suppose $S(x)=S(y)$? But if we suppose that, I guess that could be concluded, yes. Seems logical atleast.

Comment: Think about the definition of injective linear transformation, the comment by @Mark is made for any kind of functions but you can use the linear transformation characterization of injectivity S(x)=0 if and only if x = 0 and the argument is the same.

Comment: I don't understand, frankly. I'm sorry. But thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

Let $S(x)=S(y)$.

By hypothesis, $T(S(x)) = x$ and $T(S(y))=y$.

Since $T$ is a mapping, we obtain $x=T(S(x)) = T(S(y)) = y$.

Comment: Thank you, Wuestenfux!